# Basic maven issue- building a java/scala library

Tags: scala, maven

I'm sure I'm just being obtuse but I've bought the OA book, a couple of others and I'm still just as dense as before....I'm trying to build a scala library with maven and the scala plkugin, but I think this applies to Java as well.

It has no main code module, it's just a library.  If I have a class such as com.busygeeks.binklebots and source files under it, I created

```
src
  scala
     com
       busygeeks
          binklebots
             sourcefies.....
```

When I try a maven:compile, it completes successfully, but doesn't actually build anything.
I know it's very basic -- but I'm missing it.   How can I say "Take everything under src/scala and build and jar it"

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you might just need [a `main` directory](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) in there between `src` and `scala`.

If you *really* wanted to, you could specify a custom layout with the `java` and `scala` directories immediately under `src`. But you almost certainly don't want to, for the reasons given in the Maven documentation linked above.

Comment: Again, I assume this is because I am a Maven beginner, but I assume this means the _main_ directory does _not_ require that the code actually be the main class?

Comment: Right—`main` here just distinguishes your library or application code from your `test` code.